# What is the fastest way to log data to a MySQL sever within a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, database, logging, mysqli

**Preamble:**

This post is **not** about how to use PHP and MySQL, or how to write a script that logs some information to a database. This question is meant to work out the **best solution** for logging information on the most **fastest** way into a MySQL database using a PHP script! So it's truly about micro-improvements. Thank you!

---

**Situation:**

I've got a PHP script working on a server, which delivers content very fast to customers. A MySQL server is available on that machine too, so this is the weapon of choice. Now I would like to track some information about the requests. Therefore, I need to log the information somehow, and I think the best solution here is a flat database table where the information can be stored.

But I need to keep the time as low as possible for the log to have at least no impact on the response time, even on many simultaneous requests. The system has between 100K and 1M requests per day. Most of them between the working hours (*8 - 18 o'clock*). Actual response time is about ~3-5ms, so even 1ms would mean an increase of 20%.

The database table I've created is very flat and has no *extras*. Only index on that table is on the `id` column, which is an `PRIMARY` field with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, because I would like to have unique identifier for further jobs (*later on more about this*). For this post and further examples, we assume a table structure like this:

```
| id | d1  | d2  | d3  |
|----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1  | foo | bar | baz |
| 2  | foo | bar | baz |
| 3  | foo | bar | baz |
| ...
```

The processing of the recorded data will be done by another script later. So there is no need to do further actions with the data, it's all about the storage itself. But the table could be grow up to about 3M rows.

---

**Database thoughts:**

First of all I asked myself about the right database engine. My first thought was, that `Memory` would be the fastest, but we would lose all entries whenever the server is going down (*I got a weekly maintenance window for installing updates and restarting the system too*). This should not ever happen. So I came back to `MyISAM` and `InnoDB`. But which one to take?

So I made a simple benchmark, to see if there were big differences between these two engines. I've created three tables, each with another engine on my development machine and created a simple script, calculating some times.

```
CREATE TABLE `log_myisam` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `d1` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `d2` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `d3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE `log_innodb` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `d1` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `d2` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `d3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `log_memory` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `d1` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `d2` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `d3` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=Memory;
```

My test script now simply enters `1,000,000` flat lines into the tables. Afterwards calculate an average out of consumed time. Here's the benchmark script:

```
foreach( array("myisam", "innodb", "memory") as $table ) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO log_{$table} SET d1='foo',d2='bar',d3='baz'";

    $start = microtime(true);
    for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
        $sql->query($query);
    }
    $end = microtime(true);

    $results[$table] = $end - $start;
}
```

As expected, the `Memory` table was by far the fastest one. But even the `MyISAM` is every time faster than `InnoDB`. This makes sense to me, because `MyISAM` leaks support for things like `foreign keys` and `transactions`, so there is less functional overhead in this engine.

What really surprised me is the fact, that the `Memory` table is nearly as twice the size as the other tables. At this point I'm not sure why. The results:

```
                  | InnoDB    | MyISAM    | Memory    |
|-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| time for insert | 133.92 s  | 101.00 s  | 79.351 s  |
| avg. per entry  | 0.1392 ms | 0.1010 ms | 0.0794 ms |
| time saved in % | 0.0000 %  | 24.585 %  | 21.436 %  |
| table size      | 35.6   mb | 29.9   mb | 55.9   mb |
```

But as far as I know, `MyISAM` locks the table while executing an `INSERT`. This could be problematic on many simultaneous requests. But I don't know how to benchmark this.

Another question for me is, how the index of the `id` column will affect the run time. Is it helpful or will it slow down the time. So I let the benchmark script run again, after I removed the `PRIMARY` index and the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option from the `id` column.

```
                  | InnoDB    | MyISAM    | Memory    |
|-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| time with id    | 133.92 s  | 101.00 s  | 79.351 s  |
| avg. with id    | 0.1392 ms | 0.1010 ms | 0.0794 ms |
|-----------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| time without id | 131.88 s  | 91.868 s  | 73.014 s  |
| avg. without id | 0.1319 ms | 0.0919 ms | 0.0701 ms |
```

`MyISAM` seems to take the most advantage of dropping the index. But the range of the two results are not as width spreaded as expected.

---

**Query thoughts:**

The query itself has been kept simple. I would not know how to improve this any further.

```
INSERT INTO log_myisam
SET
    d1 = 'foo',
    d2 = 'bar',
    d3 = 'baz'
```

---

**PHP script thoughts:**

One thing that would cost time, is the connection itself. Because of that, I would go with a persistent connection. I've used `mysqli` of course. But is there a difference between `procedural` or `oop` usage? I've made a simple benchmark again.

```
$startProcedual = microtime(true);
for( $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++ ) {
    $sql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'benchmark');
    mysqli_close($sql);
    unset($sql);
}
$endProcedual = microtime(true);

$startOop = microtime(true);
for( $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++ ) {
    $sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'benchmark');
    $sql->close();
    unset($sql);
}
$endOop = microtime(true);
```

Without a persistent connection the difference is quite visible! The `oop` style is a bit faster, and this are only 1.000 connections.

```
procedural: 0.326150 s
oop:        0.256580 s
```

With persistent connection enabled, both versions are nearly the same. But the whole connection time dropped by one third of the normal one. So it seems the best way is to go with a persistent connection here.

```
procedural: 0.093201 s
oop:        0.092088 s
```

---

**My temporary conclusion:**

Actually I'm at a logging time of 0.204 ms (*as an avg. of 100.000 inserts*).

As for now I would say the following:

- use `MyISAM` because it's the best mix of speed, security and size
- try to drop the `id` column because of the index for more speed
- the query could not improved anymore (*imo*)
- use a persistent connection with mysqli `oop` style

But there are some open questions for me. Did I made the right decisions? Is `MyISAM` blocking the execution? Is there a way to use `Memory`? Could a persistent connection could have any side effects, like slowing down through higher memory usage? ...

I would really appreciate your ideas or tips for an even faster logging. Maybe I'm totally wrong at some points. Please let me know if you have any experiences with this kind of things.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the Engine, and I am glad not to touch that hot potato, the fastest way by far will be to use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) from CSV files that you create. So, the CSV is created in append mode as the traffic comes in. Have a mechanism to close one version down, get a new incrementor, and start fresh. Perhaps hourly. Your files may look like this when done

```
/tmp/csvfiles/traffic_20160725_00.csv
...
/tmp/csvfiles/traffic_20160725_23.csv
```

That just got you 24 hours of traffic. Upload as described above, whenever you feel like it, rest assured of two things:

- You always have a backup
- You will always outperform an `INSERT` call (by factors that will blow your mind away).

An added bonus is that your csv, let's just call them text files, are pretty much ready to rock and roll into a no sql solution when you decide that is where it might belong anyway.

Note: I am a big fan of Events. I have 3 links off my profile page for them as examples. However, Events and Stored Procs are forbidden to use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). So I have separate agents that do that. Those agents are nice because over time I naturally add different functionality to them. With the combo of Events and agents, there is never a need to use cron or other o/s schedulers.

The Takeway: Never use `INSERT` for this.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. First questions coming to my mind is, how long it takes to write the file and what time it cost if the file is locked. Time for new benchmarks. ;) Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: I even use this on a c# GUI [client](http://i.imgur.com/bVXkQ0s.jpg) I wrote that brings in stackoverflow questions (json update objects) via the same concept. Into a worktable, and with a `update with a join pattern`. So, `LOAD DATA INFILE` (uber-fast), then an update statement. No slow client looper thing. The results, 40 times faster. Note: I bring in 1000 questions at a time related to this comment.

Comment: I've made a benchmark of `file_put_contents`, `fwrite` and `fwrite` with an omitted `length`. The last was even the fastest one, with 0.38ms for a single line. But this is nearly twice the time it would took to write the same data directly into the database. And it would took a way more code to implement a file log too. So actually I don't see a usecase for file logging instead of database, if it's slower ...

Comment: I am talking about the speed at which one can acquire thousands of rows in blocks, maybe tens of thousands, and getting them inserted into a db. Strategy A vs B. And that would not be done with an insert command for those that do data ingest.

Comment: There might be a difference while executing big blocks of data. But this is not what I want to do. It is a single line per request. It could be many requests, yes, but it requires every time a open/close of connection or file handle. I think that is the main reason why file could be faster on more lines ...

Comment: I am assuming you want massive data brought in at once